# Any four points on the space curve given by the parametrization $(t,t^2,t^3)$ are noncolinear

Tags: geometry

I want to draw a space curve given by the parametrization $(t,t^2,t^3)$, Thanks to wolfram, i have an idea how it looks like but is there any way to draw this? and I want to show that any four points on this curve are noncolinear, My idea is to take an arbitrary line in $\mathbb R^3$ and show that the intersection with the curve has atmost 3 solutions, but how to do this,please help !

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Four points $(x_i, y_i, z_i)$ in 3D-space are co-plane iff there is nontrivial $(A, B, C, D)$ solution for 
$$
Ax_i+By_i+Cz_i+D=0 \quad i=1,2,3,4
$$
or 
$$
\det\pmatrix{
x_1&y_1&z_1&1\\
x_2&y_2&z_2&1\\
x_3&y_3&z_3&1\\
x_4&y_4&z_4&1\\
}=0.
$$
Plugging $(x_i,y_i,z_i)=(t_i, t_i^2, t_i^3)$ to the matrix, you may find it is Vandermonde matrix. So any four points are not coplane, hence colinear neither.

Comment: After noting that the matrix is Vandermonde, recall particular conditions on the rows for a matrix to be singular. Interpret geometrically.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Let $A(a,a^2,a^3)$ and $B(b,b^2,b^3)$, with $a\neq b$, be points on the curve, and consider the set of points $P(x,y,z) := A u + B (1-u)$ on the line joining them. Show that the choices for $u$ are pretty limited if you want $y = x^2$ and $z = x^3$.